# android NotificationCompat.Builder getNotification automatically sent notification

Tags: android, notifications, parse-platform

Hi I am trying to send a notification in BroadcastReceiver when receive a broadcast message. from Parse.com. But When call getNotification method from an instance of NotificationCompat.Builder, the notification automatically sent and displayed with a canned contextText. So when call mNotificationManager.notify, TWO notification shows up and one with specified content text and the other one without. I am on API level 16.

Following is my code in BroadcastReceiver, please help me. Thank you very much!

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString(
                    "com.parse.Data"));

            String text = json.getString("text");
            String title = json.getString("title");
            Long timestamp = json.getLong("timestamp");
            String qid = json.getString("qid");

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(text)
                    .setTicker("New Reply");

            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context,
                    QuestionViewActivity.class);
            resultIntent.putExtra(QuestionViewActivity.EXTRA_QUESTION_ID,
                    qid);

            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.from(context);
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder
                    .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            Notification n = mBuilder.getNotification();
            mNotificationManager.notify(qid.hashCode(),
                    mBuilder.getNotification());
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it:

1. For no build() method: It is caused by ActionBarSherlock using a old version of android-support-v4.jar. Just replace that jar with the updated one from /SDK/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar
2. For the duplicated notification: It is caused by Parse(parse.com) service. When receiving any Push sent with parse notification lib with "title" in the JSON data, the service automatically shows the notification with canned contentText like "you received a notification". A trick here I used to disable the automatic notification is DO NOT use "title" and "text" in the JSON data of parse Push, instead use other names and then parse it in the customized broadcast receiver. It works fine now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#build()

getNotification() is deprecated. Why not use build() ?

Comment: I don't have build() function... I updated my SDK but still no such function.....